# Best design patterns for sending SMS through multiple gateways

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

I've multiple SMS gateways and I want to send SMS though any one vendor who is having high success ratio and less in cost. I've the data ready with me of cost and success ratio.

Which design pattern will best suit to switch between SMS gateway on runtime to keep my SMS wrapper up 100% and cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

'Best' often turns out very relative but if you want to switch between the senders at runtime you could use the factory/resolver/provider:

```
public interface ISMSSenderProvider/Resolver/Factory
{
   ISMSSender GetSender()
}
```

Inside `GetSender` you can do whatever is necessary to figure out which sender to return - you could ask a db*, ask an api*, check a setting, etc.

** - probably cached*